# Write keypresses to the DOM

Tags: javascript

So, I am trying to run a function that grabs the key that was pressed and puts it in a variable.
I have tried doing:

```
let text = "";
function keys(){
    let key = KeyboardEvent.name;
    text = text + key;
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = text;
}
while(1===1){
    document.onkeypress(keys());
}
```

But it hasn't thrown any errors at me and isn't doing what I want it to do. I would like to ask someone to explain to me how I can change and fix it.

```
let text = ""
function keys(){
    let key = KeyboardEvent.name
    text = text + key
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = text
}
while(1===1){
    document.onkeypress(keys())
}
```

just doesn't work nicely.

Comment: Do you want to accumulate text to the screen (like in your example), or just write the latest keypress and delete everything else (like in the accepted answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the key pressed using `event.key` in the keypress event handler.

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  document.getElementById('key').textContent = e.key;
});
```

```html
<p id="key"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few crucial errors:

- `document.onkeypress` is a variable, not a function. You want to use `.addEventListener()` instead.
- Don't put the event listener in a loop. You only need to register the event once.
- `KeyboardEvent` is a class name, not the name of the actual event variable. Use `e.key` instead.

You also don't need a bunch of intermediate variables. Try this:

```js
function keypress(e) {
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML += e.key;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keypress);
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

However, you should always consider a `contentEditable` element instead:

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">Enter text.</div>
```